# Iterate over array of objects from txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, class, oop

I have file with records separated by comas:

cities.txt:

```
1,NYC
2,ABQ
...
```

I would like to iterate over each row: ids and names. I have created the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class City {
    int id;
    string name;

public:
    City() {}
    City(int id, int name)
    {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
    }

    void load_file()
    {
        ifstream v_file("cities.txt");
        if (v_file.is_open()) {
            while (!v_file.eof()) {
            //...
            }
        }
        v_file.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    City array_city[1000];

    array_city.load_file();

    return 0;
}
```

Could you tell me how to load all rows to array `array_city` and iterate over it? I don't know what to place in `while` block in `load_file` method. I don't know weather, the method `load_file` should have `void` type. Unfortunately I have to do it on arrays.

Comment: Aren't you be supposed to do your homework yourself?

Comment: Arrays are not classes, they cannot have methods. You need to return the array from the load function, likely with `std::vector`

Comment: @manni66 there are [rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on homework questions, they are not completely forbidden. That said OP should clarify that this is an assignment if it is

Comment: Figure out how to read the file line by line. google is your friend. Then figure out what you have to do next.

Comment: Two things: 1) don't close the file your self, rely on RAII to do it for you. 2) Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Thanks guys. I know now how to add lines to City array_city but who to iterate over it? E.G display all names from array_city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use EOF in a while loop. Read more in [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

---

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), vectors should be preferred over arrays. However, your teacher knows something more to suggest using an array here. For that reason I am providing a solution with an array:

1. Read the file line by line
2. Extract the id and the string
3. Assign it to the i-th cell of the array

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class City {
    int id;
    string name;

public:
    City() {}
    City(int id, string name) : id(id), name(name)
    {
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "ID = " << id << ", name = " << name << endl;
    }
};

void load_file(City* cities, const int n)
{
    ifstream v_file("cities.txt");
    if (v_file.is_open()) {
        int number, i = 0;
        string str;
        char c;
        while (v_file >> number >> c >> str && c == ',' && i < n)
        {
            //cout << number << " " << str << endl;
            cities[i++] = {number, str};
        }
    }
    v_file.close();
}

int main()
{
    City cities[4]; // assuming there are 4 cities in the file
    load_file(cities, 4);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cities[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Same solution with [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), if you are interested. =) If you haven't been taught about them, I suggest you skip that part and come back later when you do that in the course.

Use a vector of `City`. [Read the file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line), and push back into the vector every line you read, by constructing an instance of your class, and you are done!

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class City {
    int id;
    string name;

public:
    City() {}
    City(int id, string name) : id(id), name(name)
    {
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "ID = " << id << ", name = " << name << endl;
    }
};

void load_file(vector<City>& cities)
{
    ifstream v_file("cities.txt");
    if (v_file.is_open()) {
        int number;
        string str;
        char c;
        while (v_file >> number >> c >> str && c == ',' && i < n)
        {
            //cout << number << " " << str << endl;
            cities.push_back({number, str});
        }
    }
    v_file.close();
}

int main()
{
    vector<City> cities;
    load_file(cities);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cities.size(); ++i)
        cities[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ cat cities.txt 
1,NYC
2,ABQ
3,CCC
4,DDD
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
ID = 1, name = NYC
ID = 2, name = ABQ
ID = 3, name = CCC
ID = 4, name = DDD
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation, @gsamaras! Thanks for 2 examples.